# Iterate through linq query results from multiple tables

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a VB .Net linq query that I want to return values from two tables. I currently have this:

```
Dim query = (From c In db.Client _
                            Join u In db.Users _
                            On u.UserID Equals c.UserID _
                            Where (c.ClientID = 1)
                            Select c, u).ToList
```

query (System.Collections.Generic.List(Of )) returns several rows as expected each item containing a c and a u.

How do I iterate through the queries collection? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn on [Option Infer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx) then you can iterate over it in a foreach loop. However since it's an anonymous type you can only do it in the scope of the method you're in.